# Grep all lines ending - doesn't work

Tags: regex, grep

I use grep command to grep all lines ending com$

> grep 'com$' input > output

But result - only one line, that match pattern.

I want, that result was all lines that match  com$  pattern.

Example:

site.com

site2.com

site3.tv

site4.com

GNU grep 2.6.3

Comment: Works here, what version of `grep` are you using? And could you post an excerpt of the data your grepping?

Comment: "grep .com$ ./test.sites" works for me, where test.sites is your example data.

Comment: Can you please test your grep against the provided sample data and share the result? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using your input, it works for me.  but, could trailing spaces be a problem? try:

```
grep 'com[ ]*$' input >output
```

seeing your results would be helpful.